# Using scopes in cancan, ability.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I'm using cancancan for authorisation.

I want to allow anyone read access to users within a scope.

I have this in user.rb -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   scope :published, -> { describes scope, works happily
 }
end
```

The cancancan docs describe using scopes like this -

```
can :read, Photo, Photo.unowned do |photo|
      photo.groups.empty?
end
```

... a block acting on the scope. I just want the scope.

This seems to allow anyone to be read -

```
  can :read, User, User.published do |user|
    true
  end
```

I can't reason what block I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was making it one step more complicated than it needed to be. All that is required is -

```
can :read, User.published
```

Which on reflection makes perfect sense, but I could not get my head around.